# How to change SPI Flash size in ESP32 in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, esp32, esp-idf

In my eclipse console **Auto-detected Flash size: 4MB** is showing but in the terminal **I (55) boot: SPI Flash Size : 2MB** which is giving error because the partition table requires 4MB.

And strangely this was not the problem a week ago, everything was working fine and I checked my terminal logs from a week ago (which I saved in a separate text file because of some other error) in that **I (54) boot: SPI Flash Size : 4MB** is written. So this changed automatically I guess because I didn't change anything in the menuconfig.
I tried to find solution on the internet but couldn't find anything. Any suggestions on what should I do?

Comment: and the menuconfig?  what is set there?

Comment: @Juraj in menuconfig Flash size 4 MB is set.

Comment: I suggest visiting esp32.com where you can find a lot more people around the ESP32. You may want to post there.

Comment: To work around the error, you may also re-organize the partition table, if all the partitions together add up to less than 2MB. Have a look here: https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-guides/partition-tables.html?highlight=partition%20table

Comment: @StrawHat thanks for the suggestion. I have posted the question on ESP32 forum. And I want the partition to be of 4 MB because I have OTA and other features but appreciate the effort thanks man.